# Does active/passive voice distinction exist in imperative and subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctive, passive, tense, grammatical-mood

So, to my understanding a verb has three properties:

- Mood
- Tense
- Voice

I know so far that certain moods have certain tenses but can moods have different voices? I mean, does the active vs passive thing make sense for imperative and subjunctive?

Comment: Ein wenig sprachvergleichende Evidenz dafür, dass *sei* in diesem Fall wirklich imperative und nicht konjunktive Merkmale in sich trägt: Im Niederländischen sind die beiden Formen unterschiedlich flektiert *wees* vs. *zij(n)* und die Entsprechung zu *Sei gegrüßt!* ist *Wees gegroet!* und nicht * *Zij gegroet!*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

- Indikativ (indicative) (Statement. Say what is.)

  - Aktiv (active): Du wäscht jetzt das Auto.
  - Vorgangspassiv (passive of process): Das Auto wird jetzt gewaschen.
  - Zustandspassiv (passive of state): Das Auto ist jetzt gewaschen.
- Imperativ (imperative) (Command, request, wish)

  - Aktiv: Wasche jetzt das Auto!
  - Vorgangspassiv: Werde das Auto jetzt gewaschen!
  - Zustandspassiv: Sei das Auto jetzt gewaschen!
- Konjunktiv I (one of the two German kinds of subjunctive, mainly used for indirect speech)

  - Aktiv: Hans hat mir gesagt, du waschest jetzt das Auto.
  - Vorgangspassiv: Hans hat mir gesagt, das Auto werde jetzt gewaschen.
  - Zustandspassiv: Hans hat mir gesagt, das Auto sei jetzt gewaschen.
- Konjunktiv II (the other subjunctive form, often used as irrealis)

  - Aktiv: Ach, wüschest du endlich das Auto!
  - Vorgangspassiv: Ach, würde das Auto endlich gewaschen!
  - Zustandspassiv: Ach, wäre das Auto endlich gewaschen!

Comment: I see all of these as Konjunktiv, not Imperativ. (Except for “wasche das Auto”, of course.)

Comment: @CarstenS: Wenn der große Magier mit wallendem Mantel und spitzem Zauberhut vor einem schmutzigen Auto steht, mit den Zauberstab herumfuchtelt, eine Prise Zaubersalz auf das Auto streut und dabei mit huldvoller Betonung *»Sei das Auto jetzt gewaschen!«* sagt, dann weiß ich nicht, wie man das anders als als passiven Imperativ interpretieren könnte.

Comment: *Auto, sei jetzt gewaschen!* would be clearer as an imperative.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, Konjunktiv, sage ich doch ;)

Comment: @Rha, ja schon, aber das ist aktiv. Das wird ja das Auto als Täter direkt in der vokativen Einleitung angesprochen und dann der Befehl, etwas mit sich selbst zu machen, an es gerichtet. In »Sei das Auto jetzt gewaschen!« geht der Befehl eben ausdrücklich **nicht** an das Subjekt des Satzes. Das Auto ist also der Erdulder, nicht der Täter, und es ist trotzdem ein Befehl.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast wegen der Verwendung von *sein* + Partizip Perfekt ist es aus meiner Sicht aber syntaktisch immer noch Zustandspassiv.

Comment: @Rha: **Aktiv:** Das Agens (der Täter) steht als Subjekt im Satz. Ein allfällig vorhandenes Patiens (einen Erdulder, Erleider) findet man in einem Objekt. (Wenn man den Satz in die passive Form umwandeln kann, steht es in einem Akkusativobjekt). **Passiv:** In einem Passiv-Satz steht das Patiens im Subjekt. Falls das Agens vorhanden ist, steht es in einem Präpositionalobjekt. **Also:** Subjekt = Agens → Aktiv. Subjekt = Patiens → Passiv. Dadurch, dass man den Befehl  mittels vokativer Einleitung direkt an das Auto richtet, wandelt sich das Auto vom Patiens zum Agens. Das Auto wir ja ...

Comment: ... ganz direkt aufgefordert sich selbst zu waschen. Daher ist der Satz wenigstens semantisch ein Aktiv-Satz, auch wenn die syntaktische Konstruktion des Prädikats einer Passiv-Konstruktion entspricht. Aber der entscheidende Punkt ist nicht die Ausgestaltung des Prädikats, sondern die semantische Rolle des Subjekts.

Comment: Eine Aufforderung an das Auto, sich zu waschen, wäre: *(Auto) wasch dich!* Ein Imperativ Passiv wird meines Erachtens nicht benutzt. Anstelle von *Werd nicht erwischt!* sagt man *Lass dich nicht erwischen!* (oder *Pass auf, dass du nicht erwischt wirst!*) – *Das Auto werde gewaschen* kann kein Imperativ sein, da das Subjekt 3. Person ist und nicht fehlen kann.

Comment: Imperativ Passiv ist selten, aber nicht völlig ungebräuchlich. Die Grußformel *Sei gegrüßt!" ist ein Beispiel.